# C++ Class generates no matching function and known conversion errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, box2d

I've been learning Box2D & C++ and managed to create a simple simulation in the testbed, now I'm trying to take the simulation out of the testbed and integrate it with an SDL shell.

However the class, which formerly worked in the testbed is now generating errors when I try to instantiate it and I'm a bit confused as to why it worked perfectly in the testbed but is now throwing out variable conversion errors.

This is my class:

```
    class Ball {
    public:
        bool m_contacting;
        b2Body* m_body;
        float m_radius;

    public:
        // Ball class constructor
        Ball(b2World* world, float radius) {
        m_contacting = false;
        m_body = NULL;
        m_radius = radius;

        //set up dynamic body, store in class variable
        b2BodyDef myBodyDef;
        myBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        myBodyDef.position.Set(0, 20);
        m_body = world->CreateBody(&myBodyDef);

        //add circle fixture
        b2CircleShape circleShape;
        circleShape.m_p.Set(0, 0);
        circleShape.m_radius = m_radius; //use class variable
        b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef;
        myFixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
        myFixtureDef.density = 1;
        myFixtureDef.restitution = 0.83f;
        m_body->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef);
        m_body->SetUserData( this );
        m_body->SetGravityScale(5);//cancel gravity (use -1 to reverse gravity, etc)
        }
    ~Ball(){}
    };
```

Here is my program:

```
//FooTest class member variable
std::vector<Ball*> balls;

b2Body* body;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Define the gravity vector.
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);

    // Construct a world object, which will hold and simulate the rigid bodies.
    b2World world(gravity);

    //add ball entity to scene in constructor
    Ball* ball = new Ball(world, 1);        // Fails here
    balls.push_back(ball);

    // Prepare for simulation. Typically we use a time step of 1/60 of a
    // second (60Hz) and 10 iterations. This provides a high quality simulation
    // in most game scenarios.
    float32 timeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;
    int32 velocityIterations = 6;
    int32 positionIterations = 2;

    // This is our little game loop.
    for (int32 i = 0; i < 60; ++i)
    {
        // Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation.
        // It is generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.
        world.Step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

        // Now print the position and angle of the body.
        b2Vec2 position = body->GetPosition();
        float32 angle = body->GetAngle();

        printf("%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f\n", position.x, position.y, angle);
    }

    // When the world destructor is called, all bodies and joints are freed. This can
    // create orphaned pointers, so be careful about your world management.

    return 0;

}
```

This is the generated error:

```
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to 'Ball::Ball(b2World&, int)'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|20|note: candidates are:|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\objects.h|15|note: Ball::Ball(b2World*, float)|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\objects.h|15|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'b2World' to 'b2World*'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\objects.h|7|note: Ball::Ball(const Ball&)|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\objects.h|7|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided|
```

If I call the constructor like this

```
Ball* ball = new Ball(&world, 1);
```

I get the following errors

```
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|17|undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|35|undefined reference to `b2World::Step(float, int, int)'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|47|undefined reference to `b2World::~b2World()'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|47|undefined reference to `b2World::~b2World()'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN13b2CircleShapeC1Ev':|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\..\include\Box2D\Collision\Shapes\b2CircleShape.h|65|undefined reference to `vtable for b2CircleShape'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN4BallC1EP7b2Worldf':|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\objects.h|24|undefined reference to `b2World::CreateBody(b2BodyDef const*)'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\objects.h|34|undefined reference to `b2Body::CreateFixture(b2FixtureDef const*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN13b2CircleShapeD1Ev':|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\..\include\Box2D\Collision\Shapes\b2CircleShape.h|25|undefined reference to `vtable for b2CircleShape'|
||=== Build finished: 8 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 2 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: Your passing a reference to `world`, It appears your constructor is expecting `&world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
Ball* ball = new Ball(world, 1);
```

you use a constructor of `Ball` which does not exist, since the only ones available are `Ball(b2World* world, float radius)` and the copy constructor. If you want to use the constructor you declared, you need to pass the pointer to world:

```
Ball* ball = new Ball(&world, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the constructor as having the following parameters

```
Ball(b2World* world, float radius);
```

that is the first parameter is `pointer to 2World`. However you call it using reference to 2World instead of pointer

```
b2World world(gravity);

//add ball entity to scene in constructor
Ball* ball = new Ball(world, 1);
```

world is not pointer to b2World. So this statement

```
Ball* ball = new Ball(world, 1);
```

is invalid.

Maybe you meant

```
Ball* ball = new Ball( &world, 1 );
```

Comment: Hmm, if I use `new Ball (&world,1);` I get a lot of undefined reference errors:

'obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|17|undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|35|undefined reference to `b2World::Step(float, int, int)'|
C:\Users\Chris\My Programs\_C++\Keepie Uppie\main.cpp|47|undefined reference to `b2World::~b2World()'|
'

Comment: @Funk247 Where do you see that I advice to write the statement new Ball (&world,1); ?

Comment: Last line of your original post, I modified my code to reflect that, but only posted the last characters. Sorry I was being lazy.

Comment: Ah you were right, that ixed my issue, now my class is generating errors! Thanks for the assist.